# Physics Domain Box in Box

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, geometry

Working with the Physics sim, I noticed a small box in the corner of my DOMAIN.

What is that small box?
How do I MOVE it to center mass?

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you pls add a screenshot?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to upload a image here, but it's exactly the same as this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg656.png
https://cdn.renderguide.com/bpKGiTU.Ngn1~58515/w:862/h:667/q:90/https://renderguide.com/wp-content/uploads/blender-fluid-simulation-domain.png

Comment: ok, this is the "minimum water/gas" "pixel". So everything which is smaller than this will make problems. So if you have an inflow which is smaller than your resolution box, won't be take into account.

Comment: Thank you.  Trying to flush out an issue and....That wasn't it.

Thank you for the info.

Comment: It's like @Chris explained. The small box is the voxel size according to the _Resolution Divisions_ setting in your domain. It is a cube that's the size of the longest side of your domain's bounding box divided by the _Resolution Divisions_ setting. That's important, always the longest side - which means, if you scale your domain on the Z axis, even if the ground area on X and Y stay the same, the voxel gets larger i.e. less resolution for the simulation.

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to figure out why the exported vdb has information for only 1/4 cross section.  I was hoping that that little box 'meant something' that would lead to an ends.

Unfortunately, that wasn't it.  Thank you for the info.